# In AngularJS how to display a green tick mark in front of input field upon entering valid data in it?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, validation, passwords

I'm using AngularJS and Angular Material in my web application.

I'm a total newbie to this AngularJS and Angular Material thing.

Now I have to show a green tick mark in front of input field only upon entering valid input data in it.

How should I achieve this?

Sample password field code is as below:

```html
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex> 
    <label>Current Password</label> 
    <md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons/ic_lock_black_24px.svg"></md-icon>
    <input type="password" ng-model="changePassword.currentPassword" required name="curPass" minlength="6">
    <div ng-messages="chnagePasswordForm.curPass.$error">
        <div ng-message="required">Please enter valid password</div>
        <div ng-message="minlength">Password should be of eight or more characters</div>
    </div>
    <md-button ng-disabled="chnagePasswordForm.$invalid" class="md-raised md-primary enrolBtn" ng-click="changePassword()">Save</md-button>
</md-input-container>
```

I have to display green colored tick mark in front of this password field only upon entering the valid password.

Thanks.

Comment: Use ng-class options for Image if `changePassword.currentPassword` is valid ...FYI http://wijmo.com/easy-form-validation-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried so far? Did you try just adding another icon and conditionally showing it with ng-if:

```
 <md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons/ic_lock_black_24px.svg"></md-icon>
 <md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons/my_checkmark.svg" ng-if="!changePassword.curPass.$error"></md-icon>
 <input type="password" ng-model="changePassword.currentPassword" required name="curPass" minlength="6">
```